# How to edit the file content in vi?

Tags: linux, vi

I have a text file with following content (Actual filecontains thousands of lines)

```
abcd
xyas
sasss
jddks
asa
sasa
lkkkss
asasd
```

I want the output in the folloing format.

```
abcd xyas sasss jddks
asa sasa lkkkss asasd
```

How can i acheve this?

Comment: Always four words per line? Or is it more wrapped a set column of your file?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you just want to join every 4 lines into one, you can do it with a recursive macro:

```
ggqaqqa4Jj@aq@a
```

Explanation:

- `gg` go to start of file
- `qaq` clear any previously stored macro in register `a`
- `qa` start recording a macro in register `a`
- `4J` join 4 lines into one
- `j` go down one line
- `@a` have the macro in register `a` call itself
- `q` stop recording
- `@a` call the macro in register `a` which will keep working on the file until it's done.

**An alternative in Perl**

```
perl -ni -e 'chomp;print $_, $.%4? " ":"\n"' your_file
```

**Reference**

- [Record a recursive macro](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Record_a_recursive_macro)

Comment: The `-l` option for perl will eliminate the need for the `chomp` and the "\n".

Comment: @jordanm How can it eliminate the `"\n"`?

Comment: Why is the `qaq` step necessary? If you start recording to a small letter register, the previous content is automatically overwritten.

Comment: @Marco Any reference for that?

Comment: @JosephR. Just try it: `:let @a="foobar"`, then record a macro: `qa6ddq` and display the result: `:echo @a` → `6dd`. If you record the macro as: `qA6ddq` then the commands are appended: `:echo @a` → `foobar6dd`

Comment: @JosephR. I didn't look close enough, you are only printing in conditionally, so it wouldn't. It would end every print in a newline.

Comment: @Marco Ah, but that wouldn't work if the macro is calling itself. The first call to `@a` (while I'm defining the new `@a`) will be a call to the old `@a`.

Comment: @JosephR. You're right. Only the first call fails, the rest of the file is processed using the new definition. I overlooked that. Thanks for pointing that out.